Derivative of $A\cdot b$ in respect to $A$
Let's say I have $A\cdot b$, where $A$ is a matrix and $b$ is a vector. I want to take the derivative in respect to the matrix $A$. What is the result?
What I mean is $\nabla_A (A\cdot b)$.
Background: I want to continue here, where g(x) is the Gaussian:


Unless $A$ is populated by variable values, the result is the $0$ matrix, as $A$ is constant.

This is a linear function of $A$, so it is its own derivative.

If you'd like a good answer, you should provide the context for why you're interested in the derivative of $A.$

@Chickenmancer: I mean $\nabla_A (A\cdot b)$.

Thanks for updating the question.

@Chickenmancer: I provided more background.

$Ab$ is a vector ; the derivative of a vector w.r.t. a matrix is a third order tensor with components $\delta_l^i b^k$ where $Ab=(Ab)^i e_i$ and $b=b^k e_k$.

@TedBlack: I am not familiar with your notation. What does $(Ab)^i$ mean? What is $e$? I guess $\delta_l^i$ means a derivative, but I am not sure what.

For a vector $x$ its components w.r.t. a basis ${e_1,\ldots,e_n}$ are written as $x^i$ and so using Einstein notation $x=x^ie_i$. $\delta_l^i$ are the components of a second order mixed tensor with $\delta_l^i=1$ if $i=l$ and zero otherwise. $(Ab)^i$ means that $Ab$ is a vector whose components w.r.t. same basis are $(Ab)^i$.
